# call command in a shell script with inline environment vars

Tags: bash, shell, environment

I have two scripts

**foo.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

KEY1="1" KEY2="2" KEY3="3" ./bar.sh
```

and **bar.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $KEY1 $KEY2 $KEY3
```

the expected *./foo.sh* out is:

```
1 2 3
```

But I need put inline *key=values* in a var, say:

**foo.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

VAR ='KEY1="1" KEY2="2" KEY3="3"'

$VAR ./bar.sh
```

How I can doit ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `env` as long as the `VAR` variable splits nicely:

```
$ VAR="KEY1=value1 KEY2=value"
$ env $VAR bash -c 'declare -p ${!KEY*}'
  declare -x KEY1="value1"
  declare -x KEY2="value"
```

Comment: Don't use a regular parameter, though; use an array. `VAR=(KEY1="a b" KEY2="b c"); env "${VAR[@]}" bash -c 'declare -p ${!KEY*}'`.

Comment: @user2280250 chepner makes a very good point, though. If you can avoid the string, do it. Without the quotes, my solution might be sufficient. With the quotes, you'd need eval and eval has massive security problems if you hand it anything you haven't crafted yourself.

Comment: Sorry!, I not follow you. Why an array?

Comment: @user2280250 Because it's more generic, as it allows you to have `*` and whitespace in the key values without having to worry about failure from `env` or the security implications of using `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn an extra shell:

```
bash -c "$vars commmand"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send it to eval:

```
eval "$VAR command"
```